# Extract section names and starting pages from a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have an [input text file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/text) looking like this ("..." is not actually in the original text, but is used by me to ignore some lengthy and likely irrelevant text; ^L" represents the start of each page (note: "^L" is typed as a control character, not character "^" and character "L")):

```
(Begin text)

.. A language ...

^LIntroduction

6

A preferable alternative is ...

1.2.1 Abstraction by Parameters 
Abstraction allows us, ...

^L1.2 Abstraction

7

and ...

1.2.2 Abstraction by Specification 
... ...
^LAn Overview of CLU

14

In addition to ...

2.1.2 Type Checking
...

(End text)
```

The desired output is:

```
1.2.1 Abstraction by Parameters 6    
1.2.2 Abstraction by Specification 7    
2.1.2 Type Checking 14
```

What I want to do is to extract **the third level section names** and **the page numbers where they appear**.

- **A third level section name** always appear in a single line.
- **The page number where a third level section name appears** is the first number appearing in a single line and right after the  last "^L" before the section name.

I wonder how to write a program in Python to accomplish that?

Here is what I have thought so far:

- The regex pattern for matching **a third level section name** is `^\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*\n`
- **in each page**, "^L" represents the start of the page (note: "^L" is typed as a control character, not character "^" and character "L"). The regex pattern for matching **the part from "^L" to the page number of the page** is `^^L.*\n.*^\s*\d+\s*\n`

I am still not sure how to continue. Thanks for your enlightment!

Comment: please remove `>`  symbols from the input. `> .. A language ...`

Comment: i mean the formatting. is this `r'^\^'` regex matches string `^` symbol?

Comment: just post the actual file contents. I'll edit your post.

Comment: is spaces exists at the start? Is there a blank line exists in-between?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There may or may not be spaces at the start of each line. There may or may not be a blank line between two text lines.  I gave some observations that may help to identify the 3rd level section names and page numbers in the post.

Comment: problem is mainly with matching the control character. is this `r'^\^'` regex matches  ^ symbol?

Comment: Do you mean Python can't match control characters, even if I copy the control character into the regex pattern? If that stops you, replacing the control character with some other normal character, now can we solve the problem?

Comment: how about matching the line which contain only a single number?

Comment: That may not work, because some pages don't show  page numbers due to some error. To know if  a page shows a page number, we have to know where a page starts, which is represented by the control character.

Comment: @Tim, i didn't understood the last comment. [this is that iv'e done so far](https://ideone.com/fH2yzm)

Comment: @Jossef: Thanks! (1) In the output, the last line also has a page number, while your program doesn't find it. (2) When a 3rd level section name appears in a page and the page doesn't show its page number (which should appears after "^J" of the page), your program will find the page number of some previous page instead.

Comment: @Tim, [check this out](https://ideone.com/fH2yzm)

Comment: @Jossef: Thanks! What does the value you give to the page separator? By the way, I upload the text as a file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have knowledge of the text - I needed to inspect it closely to craft this.  Page numbers look like - `FormFeedPageNoLineFeed` or `LineFeedPageNoLineFeed` and there can be multiple third level *headings* on a page so start with a regular expression that will extract whole pages and capture the page number.

```
pages = re.compile(r'[\n\f](\d+)\n.*?(?=[\n\f](\d+)\n)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Then search each page for third level *headings* and put it all together.

```
third_level = re.compile('\n(\d+\.\d+\.\d+[^\n]*)')
for page in pages.finditer(s):
    page_no = page.group(1)
    for item in third_level.finditer(page.group()):
        print '{}\t{}'.format(item.group(1), page_no)
```

This produces 54 third level headings.  Unfortunately it is unique to your text. In the time it took me to figure this out I could have extracted the info semi-manually with a good text editor that can do regular expression searches (which is what I did to figure it out and validate it).

You might be able to refine `pages` - the `.*?` combined with the lookahead assertion smells a bit.

---

**Edit to extract first and second level headings then combine with the third level headings.**  Unique for OP's file [`stuff.txt`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/text)

```
import re
with open('stuff.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Extract the contents and appendix info, the appendices are extracted separate to simplify the *merge*.

```
content_item = re.compile('\d+\.?\d*? [^\n]*')
appendix_item = re.compile('Appendix[^\n]*|[ABC]\.[^\n]*')

# Indices to limit the contents search
content_start = re.search('\f\fContents', s).span()[1]
content_end = re.search('\f\fPreface', s).span()[0]

content_items = content_item.findall(s, content_start, content_end)
appendices = appendix_item.findall(s, content_start, content_end)
```

Now find all the third level headings and page numbers- same as above but store in a list,

```
third_level = re.compile('\n(\d+\.\d+\.\d+[^\n]*)')
pages = re.compile(r'[\n\f](\d+)\n.*?(?=[\n\f](\d+)\n)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

third_levels = list()

for page in pages.finditer(s, content_end):
    page_no = page.group(1)
    for item in third_level.finditer(page.group()):
        third_levels.append('{}\t{}'.format(item.group(1), page_no))
```

Combine the contents and third_level headings, sort, and add the appendix headings.

```
a = content_items + third_levels

def key(item):
    '''Extract digits from the beginning of item for a sort key.

    item is a string
    >>> key('1 ABC')
    (1, None, None)
    >>> key('1.2 ABC')
    (1, 2, None)
    >>> key('1.2.3 ABC')
    (1, 2, 3)
    >>>
    '''
    item = item.split()
    item = item[0].split('.')
    a, b, c = None, None, None
    try:
        a = int(item[0])
    except ValueError as e:
        pass
    try:
        b = int(item[1])
    except IndexError as e:
        pass
    try:
        c = int(item[2])
    except IndexError as e:
        pass
    return a, b, c

a.sort(key = key)
a.extend(appendices)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works as desired. Suppose I have  regex's  `second_level` and `first_level` for other levels of sections and chapters. How can we go on to create some code based on your curent one, to output the sections' titles,  page numbers and levels, in the order they are shown in the original text? (e.g. `1 This is a chapter   1 1`, ..., `2.1 This is a section 30 2`, ..., `4.3.2 This is a subsection 60 3`)?

Comment: @Tim - I guess I would try and extract that directly from the Contents section and store it in a collection.  Then use the code above and store all the third level stuff in the collection.  Then sort the collection on the heading *number*.

Comment: Thanks. (1) The reason I mentioned extracting other levels not from Table of Content but from the main text, is because other text files might not have Table of Content. (2) Suppose having extracted headings of all levels, to recreate the Table of Content, do we have to sort them according to their positions in the text file and indent them according to their levels?

Comment: (1)Remember that this is unique to the text you referred to, I found some inconsistencies in the patterns that appeared arbitrary (I didn't account for a couple). (2) I had thought of a different approach, ```re.match``` objects do have ```start```, ```end```, and ```span``` methods that return the indices of the match - you could use them for the sorting.  Maybe create a pattern that would match (PageNo OR LevelOne OR LevelTwo Or LevelThree OR Appendix), find and save all the matches, sort by the positions, construct indentation on how many dots there are(?) - as a start anyway.

Answer (score 1):

the character you need to delimit by is `\x0C` / `^L` / `chr(12)` which is the [*Page Break*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) character.

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/fH2yzm)**

**iterative method**

```
import re

def foo(lines):
    name = ''
    pages = []
    page_break_char = chr(0xC)

    for line in lines:

        if re.match('^\s*\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*', line):
            name = line
        elif re.match('^\d+$', line):
            pages.append(line)
        elif page_break_char in line:

            if name:
                yield name, pages

            del pages[:]

    if name:
        yield name, pages
```

**usage**

```
text = '''

.. A language ...

\x0CIntroduction

6

A preferable alternative is ...

1.2.1 Abstraction by Parameters 
Abstraction allows us, ...

\x0C1.2 Abstraction

7

and ...

1.2.2 Abstraction by Specification 
... ...
\x0CAn Overview of CLU

14

In addition to ...

2.1.2 Type Checking ...

'''

lines = text.split('\n')
for name, pages in foo(lines):
    print name, ' '.join(pages)
```

**output**

[image]

---

## Online Demo

### https://ideone.com/fH2yzm

Comment: +1 Thank you so much! Here is [the original lengthy text](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/text), more lengthy than the simplified text I gave earlier. Your program runs smoothly on it, though the output has  repeated detections although each 3rd level section name appears just once, and page numbers of some detections are not found although shown, some detections have more than one page numbers found. Do we oversimplified our assumptions on  the text?